# jquery validation onSubmit ajax post JSON response

Tags: json, jquery, validation, return-value

I have a very complicated post using jquery validation and an AJAX post that gets a JSON response back from the server and puts it in a jqGrid...  But it seems as though my onsuccess is never being called at any point...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formSearchByMRN").validate({
        rules: {
            MRN: { required: true, minLength: 6 }
        },
        messages: {
            MRN: 'Please Enter a Valid MRN'
        },            
        submmitHandler: function (form) {
            e.preventDefault();
            animateLoad();
            debugger;                
            var theURL = form.action;
            var type = form.methd;
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: theURL,
                type: type,
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    var data = result;
                    if (data.split(':')[0] == "Empty record") {
                        $("#list").unblock();
                        $('#resultDiv').html('<b><p style="color: #ff00ff">' + data + '</p></b>');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#resultDiv').html("");
                        }, 10000);
                    }
                    else {
                        binddata(data);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

It would seem I never get into the submmitHandler.  Event though I manage to get to my server side function and it does return, it prompts my UI to save a file which contains the JSON results... 
No good.
Am I going about validating my form before my AJAX post the wrong way?  Does anybody have any advice about best practices in validating AJAX posts?

UPDATE...  MARK R.  This is what I attempted.  It seems as though I never get in to the success function... My suspicion is that I am not really posting via ajax, but instead doing a full post.  I don't understand why.

```
$('#submitMRN').click(function () {
    $("#formSearchByMRN").validate({
        rules: {
            MRN: { required: true, minLength: 6 }
        },
        messages: {
            MRN: 'Please Enter a Valid MRN'
        }
    });
    if ($('#submitMRN').valid()) {
        $("#list").block({ message: '<img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />' });
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#submitMRN').action,
            type: $('#submitMRN').method,
            data: $('#submitMRN').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                var data = result;
                if (data.split(':')[0] == "Empty record") {
                    $("#list").unblock();
                    $('#resultDiv').html('<b><p style="color: #ff00ff">' + data + '</p></b>');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#resultDiv').html("");
                    }, 10000);
                }
                else {
                    binddata(data);
                }
            }                    
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: So your "submmitHandler:" function is firing?

Comment: something is firing.  But I do not seem to be hitting the debbugging statement.

Comment: And is your MRN field validating? aka will it show as red with an error message when the conditions are not met?

Comment: it will show the red error message when the condition is not met.  But the functionality is just not there.  I just returned to my original implementation of a submit and got rid of Submit handler, because it was simply not working.  I am trying to come up with another way to validate my form before I submit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#SubmitButton').click(function (){
        //Check that the form is valid
        $('#FormName').validate(); 
        //If the Form is valid 
        if ($('#FormName').valid()) { 
            $.post(...........
        }
        else { 
            //let the user fix their probems
            return false; 
        }
    });//$('#SubmitButton').click(function (){
```

Comment: Not really that helpfull in the context of my code.  As you can see, I have some fields in my Validate code that I want to validate... Could you please elaborate.

Comment: The first $('#FormName').validate(); will validate your form, only if it is then valid will the second part pass and then you could either manually post to the server, or call the form submit.  So if your fields are not valid $('#FormName').valid() will return false.

Comment: does that go in a document.ready call?  Im positive you just can't slap that code on there and expect it to work?  Could you please expand your example to clarify.

Comment: That does make more sense, but this is supposed to be an ajax call that does something when data is returned succesfully.  JSON data is returned remember.

Comment: I'm confused...why can you use the Data that is passed back in the JSON?

Comment: I don't understand your question?  Too clarify, I had a web form that assynchronously submitted my form and returned JSON to a grid I am populating with it.  I want to now validate that form before I make my ajax submit call.

Comment: lol, what? You submit a form via ajax, which triggers the load of a jqgrid...Do you mean you want to validate your form BEFORE you submit the data via ajax?

Comment: Dude I spit out my coffee when I read that.  That is exactly what I just said.  Go back and read it.  Let me copy and paste me response last time but CAPITALIZE the key part...
 I want to now validate that form BEFORE I make my ajax submit call.

Comment: The above code will do exactly that... if it's a valid form you can post to the server...then you could test that the server manipulated your data correctly by returning a "success" json element, and then if the ajax was successful, load/reload your jqgrid.  If it's not valid it is not going to get past the ".valid" check.

Comment: pretty sure you missed a closing ')' btw.

Comment: lol... Well, it still doesn't work.  I can submit something, but I can't get into the success function.  It always asks me to save a file.  Before I added this jquery validation I was successfully updating my grid.  I don't get it?  I wouldn't have thought that this would have been such an outlandish case?  I thought there would have been many simple examples of how to do this all over the web.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing when you pass back the data to the server, or what would be triggering that.  Really it is this simple.  Validate your input. If it's valid pass it to your server.  If the server returns that your update was successful do something else, if not let the user know.

Comment: MARK.  I just updated my post with how I attempted to implement your solution.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: Looks reasonable, the only thing I thought of when looking at it is on your return function you might want to pass along a Boolean if your ajax submission succeeded on the server.  The test you have now would be true for any response, even a negative one (but then I don't know what you are doing on the server) but if your server side code failed you might have issues with your subsequent javascript.